# Recursive function taking functions as arguments

Tags: functions, recursion

I'm trying to implement Lie brackets and derivatives of nth order. 
For doing this, I've stumbled upon something I don't understand. Here is an illustration: First I define the functions:

```
Operator[f_, g_, x__, opt_] := 
 Piecewise[{{f[x], opt == 1}, {Operator[f, g, g[x], 1], opt==2}}]
ff[x__] := {x[[2]], x[[1]]}
gg[x__] := {-x[[1]], -x[[2]]}
```

Then I ask for these evaluations

```
Operator[ff, gg, {x1, x2}, 2]
Operator[ff, gg, gg[{x1, x2}], 1]
ff[gg[{x1, x2}]]
```

The results I found were:

```
{-x1, -x2}
{-x2, -x1}
{-x2, -x1}
```

The first result is actually just `gg[{x1,x2}]`, while I wanted it to be the same as the third result `ff[gg[{x1,x2}]]`, and the second result worked as I expected.

Anyone has an idea about this problem? Is there some language detail I don't know? Because the first result simply makes no sense to me right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not get the same results. If I do

```
ClearAll[Operator, ff, gg, x1, x2]
Operator[f_, g_, x__, opt_] := 
 Piecewise[{{f[x], opt == 1}, {Operator[f, g, g[x], 1], opt == 2}}]
ff[x__] := {x[[2]], x[[1]]}
gg[x__] := {-x[[1]], -x[[2]]}
```

then

```
{Operator[ff, gg, {x1, x2}, 2],
 Operator[ff, gg, gg[{x1, x2}], 1],
 ff[gg[{x1, x2}]]}
```

-> {{-x2, -x1}, {-x2, -x1}, {-x2, -x1}}

I think the function could then have been defined as

```
ClearAll[Operator]
Operator[f_, g_, x__, 1] := f[x]
Operator[f_, g_, x__, 2] := f[g[x]]
```

In which case we also have

```
{Operator[ff, gg, {x1, x2}, 2],
 Operator[ff, gg, gg[{x1, x2}], 1],
 ff[gg[{x1, x2}]]}
```

-> {{-x2, -x1}, {-x2, -x1}, {-x2, -x1}}

Comment: Your answer is right. My exemple was wrong, I got the same output after clearing all variables.

However, I couldnt' adapt your alternative to the code for Lie derivative I'm working on:

        LieD[f_, h_, x__, u__, n_] := Simplify[Piecewise[{
        {h[x], n == 0},
        {D[h[x], {x}].f[x, u], n == 1},
        {LieD[f, LieD[f, h, x, u, 1], x, u, n - 1], n > 1}}]]
    fe2[x__, u_] := {x[[1]]^2/2 + Exp[x[[2]]]+x[[2]],x[[1]]^2}
    he2[x__] := x[[1]]
    LieD[fe2, he2, {x1, x2}, u, 1]
    LieD[fe2, he2, {x1, x2}, u, 2]

Comment: @Mefitico I think in your last code it is a bad idea to make the argument pattern like you have made it. Note that two BlankSequences (__) in row is either ambiguous or at least misleading. In `LieD[f_, h_, x__, u__, n_]` you have x__ and u__ in a row. So if I enter LieD[1,2,3,4,5,6,7] then we it is confusing what x and u must be. I think you want to pass lists as arguments, but then you can just use `LieD[f_, h_, x_, u_, n_]:=`. That is also consistent with your use of Part ([[]]). My advice is to also use `fe2[x_,u_]:=` and `he[x_]:=`. I hope that helps, otherwise maybe I can help more.